# My Html span element is pushing its content into the next span pushed into its container, Is there a way to make it retain its own properties in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Within in my code I am trying to make a page to order the values its given through an input. Upon
clicking the input's submit button I create .InnerHTML and push it into a html container. The innerHTML is within Span tags. I would like to be able to add values within the span tag, such as a name or number. I can add a name; but upon submitting another value and thus adding another element into the container, the older span loses its properties to the new one. Any help or suggestions are appreciated. If there are any glaring mistakes in this code, aside from the issue I'm asking about, please feel free to comment. I'm here to learn and to do so I got to know when I'm screwing up. Thank You.

** Very Basic HTML below**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Order Divs</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <input type="number" id="point-input">
  <button id="sub-btn">Submit</button>
    <button id=order>Order Button</button>
    <button id="add-btn">Add</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

** Javascript Below **

```
//variables below

let orderBtn=document.getElementById("order")
console.log(orderBtn)

let addBtn=document.getElementById("add-btn")
console.log(addBtn)

const container=document.getElementById("container")
console.log(container)


let numArr=[]

let numInc=1

let numToBeRe=[]

let child=document.getElementsByClassName(`child${numInc}`)
console.log(`child${numInc}`)

let subBtn=document.getElementById("sub-btn")
console.log(subBtn)

let pointInput=document.getElementById("point-input")
console.log(pointInput)

let numbers=document.querySelector(".numbers")
console.log(numbers)



//adding an event listener to the submit button below 

subBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
let pointInput=document.getElementById("point-input")   
    console.log(pointInput.value)
        numToBeRe.push(pointInput.value) //push the input field value to an array
            console.log(numToBeRe)
//              console.log(typeof(pointInput.value))
                    pointInput=parseInt(pointInput.value)
                    console.log(pointInput)
                    
                        console.log(numToBeRe)
                            numToBeRe.sort(function(a,b){return b-a}) //sort the input to the array from highest to low
                                console.log(numToBeRe)

                                    
                                        


                    
                                        let hp=0;
                                        let name="";
                                        let weapns="";


                                    //Adding html literals on the onclick   

        container.innerHTML+=
        `<span class="child${numInc} child">
        <div class="numbers"></div>
                <div class="name-display"></div>
                    <input class="name-input">
                    <button class="name-sub-btn">Submit</button>

                    <div class="hp-display"></div>
                    <input class="hp-input">
                    <button class="hp-sub-btn">Submit</button>


                    <div class="weapons-display"></div>
                    <input class="weapons-input">
                    <button class="weapons-sub-btn">Submit</button>
        </span>`
                                            numInc=numInc+1 //incrementing the childrens id
                                    console.log(`child${numInc}`)           
                                empty()
                            
let numbers=document.querySelectorAll(".numbers")
        console.log(numbers)
                for(let i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
                    console.log(numbers[i])
                            for(let i=0;i<numToBeRe.length;i++){
                                console.log(numToBeRe[i])
                                    numbers[i].innerText=numToBeRe[i]; 
                    }}






// Name variables per constainer
let nameBtn=document.querySelectorAll(".name-sub-btn")
console.log(nameBtn)

let nameInput=document.querySelector(".name-input")
console.log(nameInput)

let nameDisplay=document.querySelector(".name-display")
console.log(nameDisplay);

for(let i=0;i<nameBtn.length;i++){
    console.log(nameBtn[i])

nameBtn[i].addEventListener("click",()=>{
    nameDisplay.innerText=nameInput.value
    console.log(child)

let theSphere=document.querySelector(".child")
console.log(theSphere)



    nameInput.value="";

})}})






function empty(){
    document.getElementById("point-input").value="";    // empty the input field after a submit
}

const childOfCont=document.getElementsByClassName("child")
console.log(childOfCont)
```

Comment: It sounds like you just need to get the current content of your output container then add the new content instead of replacing the existing content each time

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly?

Comment: Huangism, is there a specific method I should go about that with?

Comment: And what do you mean trincot by indenting it properly,  should it all be to the left? I guess I just don't know what the standard indentation is. Could you explain further by anychance?